# {{#each this}} in handlebars doesn't work if "this" is empty string

Tags: javascript, json, handlebars.js

consider my json is like this:

```
{
    main: {
        "" : [{some_obj},{some_obj}]
    },
    secondary: {
        "key": [{some_obj},{some_obj}]
    }
}
```

Now my first #each will be running for main and secondary.

```
{{#each this}}
    -- This is for main and secondary --
    {{#each this}}
        -- This is for "" in case of main and "key" in case of secondary --
    {{/each}}
{{/each}}
```

My nested #each won't work if "this" is empty as shown in my json for "main" attribute

Comment: recently we upgraded to newer version of handlebars.js. Not sure if it has to do anything with this problem.

Comment: It appears you should accept the posted answer perhaps?

Answer (score 1):

Seems like 3.x.x had a bug that caused this. 
[Here's the commit that fixes this](https://github.com/wycats/handlebars.js/commit/1bb640b) in 4.0.0.

I checked these versions with the snippet below:

4.x.x: OK

3.x.x: not OK

2.0.0: OK

```js
var data = {
  main: {
    "": [1, 2, 3]
  },
  secondary: {
    "key": [3, 4, 5]
  }
};
var compiled = Handlebars.compile(document.getElementById('temp').innerHTML);
document.write(compiled(data));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/handlebars.js/4.0.5/handlebars.js"></script>
<script id="temp" type="text/x-handlebars-template">
  {{#each this}}
    {{@key}}<br>
    {{#each this}}
      &nbsp;&nbsp;"{{@key}}": {{this}}<br>
    {{/each}}
  {{/each}} 
</script>
```